# Trying to find number of times an ID # appears in a data list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list 500 Master Account IDs, and a second sheet with a list of 1000+ child account IDs.
Each of the child accounts is linked to a unique Master ID from the 1st sheet.

I need to summarize as a count of how many child accounts each of the master account ID have.

Trying to use SUMIF or COUNTIF, but unsure how to set the parameter to look up each of the different Master ID references. 
Do  use a combined VLOOKUP. A little confused so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are the child accounts `linked`

Comment: Hi Ron, they are linked by the Master A/C ID. All good though as i worked this out yesterday